# Set a protocol buffer field from another field

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a message like this:

```
import "data.proto"

message topMessage {
    optional string foo = 1;

    message nestedMessage {
        required int index = 1;
        required data entry = 2;
    }
    repeated map = 2;
}
```

What I would like to do is have `index` set itself based on `entry`.  Every `data` message has an int field that gets used for this.  Right now I'm calling `setEntry(someData)` and `setIndex(someData.getInt())`.  It would be nice to be able to have `entry` set up so that it automatically sets `index` whenever I call `setEntry()`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which language you were using this in. Nor is there sufficient information to reproduce your problem. That being said, as a general rule, no, that cannot be specified in your .proto file. You may be able to override stuff in your code such that you call something like `setFullEntry(someData)` and that method calls both `setEntry` and `setIndex`, but that depends on the language you're using for the actual logic.

Comment: I knew that was option, but one I wanted to avoid since I don't want to readd that method to the generated code every time I compile.  Sticking with `setEntry` and `setIndex` will work, was just wondering if I could set up the .proto file to do it for me.